# Does ONLY the ellipse have these properties?

Tags: conic-sections, plane-geometry, plane-curves, affine-geometry

Two parallel lines are tangent to an ellipse. Between those two lines, every line parallel to those two intersects the ellipse in two points.

The precise midpoint between those two points lies exactly on the line connecting the two points of tangency.

My question here is whether that last proposition is true for every pair of parallel tangents **only** for the ellipse and no other shape.

**PS:** For present purposes, let's define "tangent" as "touching but not crossing the boundary." Then an oblique line through the corner of a rectangle is a "tangent", and we see that the rectangle is NOT an example of another shape with the property of interest.

**PPS:** ok, Let's refine the statement of the problem a bit. Consider a closed bounded set with non-empty interior in the plane. Suppose it is strictly convex, i.e. every point between two of its points is one of its interior points. This entails that a line that intersecting its boundary but not its interior intersects it at only one point. Call such a line a tangent line. It follows that for every tangent line, there is exactly one other tangent line parallel to it. Suppose that for every line parallel to those two and between them, the midpoint of the intersection of that line with our closed bounded convex set is on the line connecting the two points of tangency.

Does it follow that our closed bounded set is the convex hull of an ellipse?

Comment: Does the property hold for *any* two parallel tangents of the shape?

Comment: What about a rhombus ?

Comment: I think you have to restrict to convex shape with smooth boundary. Or a rectangle is another example.

Comment: So... it is possible in a rhombus too, right ?

Comment: [Curves of constant width](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_of_constant_width)?

Comment: Just to mention it: If we replace *"Between those two lines, every line parallel to those two [tangents] intersects the ellipse in two points."* with *"Every secant line parallel to those two [tangents] intersects the ellipse in two points."*, then the property holds for hyperbolas. Likewise, an appropriately-massaged variant holds for parabolas, as well.  ... That said, I suspect OP's use of "between" is intentional, and speaks to a specific interest in bounded curves.

Comment: @g.kov : This doesn't come close to working with a Reuleaux triangle. $\qquad$

Comment: $a^2x^4 + b^2y^4=1$ and also $ x^4 +2a x^2 y^2+by^4=k^2$ provided that $a^2-b<0$.

Comment: @Raffaele : Did you mean $$\Big( a^2x^4 + b^2y^4 = 1 \text{ and also } x^4 + 2ax^2y^2 + by^4 = k^2 \Big) \text{ provided that } a^2-b<0,$$ or did you mean $$a^2x^4 + b^2y^4 = 1 \text{ and also } \Big(  x^4 + 2ax^2y^2 + by^4 = k^2 \text{ provided that } a^2-b<0,\Big) \text{ ?}$$

Comment: @MichaelHardy your property is valid for every single conic: ellipse, parable, hyperbole and circle because all the conics are equivalent in the projective space. There are many proofs for this fact but they all are a bit lenghty

Comment: @hellofriends : But in projective spaces there's no such thing as the midpoint between two points.

Comment: @hellofriends : Nor can you find two parallel tangents to a parabola, and  indeed there are no parallel lines in the projective plane.

Comment: @Raffaele : How did you reach this conclusion? I'm looking at the curve $x^4+y^4=1,$ at the point where $x=-1/2$ and $y\approx 0.9839948,$ and $dy/dx$ at that point is $\approx0.1311993\,.$ Looking at a line parallel to that tangent line and a bit below it, it looks to me as if it goes a lot further to the right before it bumps into the curve than to the left. And there is the argument posted below by Christomath. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I noticed this https://imgur.com/9kjYKTL

Comment: @Raffaele : How exactly does that graphic address the question that is asked here? $\qquad$

Comment: I deeply apologize! Next time I'll use google translator sooner: I totally misunderstood the problem. In $x^4+y^4=1$ the locus of the midpoins that you describe is a fancy "S" shaped curve and not a segment as it happens with the ellipse...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Every closed convex piecewise-differentiable curve with the given tangent property is an ellipse.**

*Proof*: The problem is affine, in the sense that if a curve has the given property then so does any affine transformation of it. So, starting with a pair of tangents at the widest extent of the curve, use a rotation to make the tangents vertical and a shear to bring the curve to  $\mathcal{C}$ whose line of symmetry is the $x$-axis.

[image] $\hspace{2cm}\mapsto\hspace{2cm}$ [image]

Now take the horizontal pair of tangents on  $\mathcal{C}$, meeting it at two points one vertically above the other. Translate it so this vertical line is the $y$ axis. Then   $\mathcal{C}$ is symmetric about both the $x$ and $y$ axes. Scaling along these axes brings their intercepts to $1$. Every other point has radius at most $1$, by the way the original tangents were chosen.

**Proposition 1.  $\mathcal{C}$ is balanced, i.e., $x\in \mathcal{C}\implies -x\in\mathcal{C}$.**

This follows directly from the symmetry along the two perpendicular axes.

Hence given any pair of tangents, the line joining the points of contact passes through the origin.

**Proposition 2. The curve is differentiable.**

Join opposite corners by a line through the origin. Then $\mathcal{C}$ would have equal distances from this line along two sets of parallel lines, which gives a contradiction.

$\hspace{4cm}$[image]

**Proposition 3. Any point on $\mathcal{C}$ with radius $1$ has a perpendicular tangent.**

A point with the maximum radius $r(\theta)=1$ must have $r'=0$.

**Proposition 4. If $OA$ and $OB$ have radii of $1$ then so does their angle bisector $OC$.**

The tangent parallel to $AB$ touches the curve at some point $C$. The line $OC$ cuts $AB$ in half by hypothesis and is thus the median and angle bisector of $AOB$, and perpendicular to $AB$. Thus $\mathcal{C}$ is symmetric about $OC$ and so the tangent at $C$ is perpendicular to $OC$.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Let the tangent at $C$ meet the tangent at $A$ at the point $P$. Consider tangents parallel to $AC$ and the line $Q'OQ$ joining the opposite tangents. This line passes through the midpoint of $AC$ by hypothesis. In the limit, nearby points $A'$ on $AP$ and $C'$ on $CP$ with $A'C'$ parallel to $AC$ are also bisected by $OQ$ since $AP$ and $CP$ are tangents to $\mathcal{C}$. But this means that $OQ$ is the median of $APC$, and thus $Q$ is on $OP$. Since $OAPC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral with diameter $OP$, the bisected chord $AC$ is perpendicular to $OP$ and so $OC=OA=1$.

**Proposition 5. $\mathcal{C}$ is a circle.**

Since the $x$ and $y$ intercepts have radius $1$, one can keep taking the angle bisectors, forming a dense set of points of radius $1$. By continuity, all points have the same radius.

Hence the original curve is an affine transformation of a circle, namely an ellipse.

Comment: In the paragraph before Proposition 1 you wrote "Then $\mathcal C$ is symmetric about both the $x$ and $y$ axes." How did you reach that conclusion based only on the curve having the given propperties?

Comment: For any two tangents, the shape is symmetric along a skew-reflection. $\mathcal{C}$ is not the original curve but a rotated and sheared version. However it still satisfies the property of the question and thus the reflection property.

Comment: ok, Now we (or at least I) face the question of what to make of Raffaele's comment under the question. $\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$and some numerical work and graphics seems to turn up a counterexample to Raffaele's claim$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: Is this, or something of which it is a special case, or the technique you applied here, in the literature somewhere? $\qquad$

Comment: Brilliant resolution !

Comment: @MichaelHardy The first paragraph is a technique - to 'simplify' a problem by transformations. The rest I thought of in bed over three dawns :)

Comment: I posted a reference request about this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3804232/reference-request-where-does-this-proposition-about-ellipses-appear-in-the-lite